# Hazards in a 4-bit up/down counter

Tags: vhdl, counter

We're trying to make a 4-bit up and down counter with the options to stop the counting, or load a number and then start the count.

A problem occurs when we do the post-route simulation. The output changes when the clock is at `'0'`, and there are multiple hazards/glitches that last for about 25-30 ps every time the output changes.
[image]
(click to enlarge)

Can somebody explain why this occurs?

```
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_SIGNED.ALL;

entity esame2 is
    Port ( clock : in  STD_LOGIC;
       reset : in  STD_LOGIC;
       start_stop : in  STD_LOGIC;
       up_down : in  STD_LOGIC;
       value : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
       insert : in  STD_LOGIC;
       num : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0));
end esame2;

architecture RTL of esame2 is
    signal vet : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
begin
    process(reset, clock)
    begin 
        if reset = '1' then
            vet <= "0000";
        elsif (clock'event and clock = '1') then
            if(start_stop = '0' and reset = '0') then
                vet <= vet;
            elsif(insert = '1' and start_stop = '1' and reset = '0') then
                vet <= value;            
            elsif(insert = '0' and reset = '0' and start_stop='1' and up_down ='1')then
                if(vet = "1111") then
                    vet <= "0000";
                    else vet <= vet + 1;
                end if;
            elsif(up_down = '0')then
                if(vet = "0000") then
                    vet <= "1111";
                    else vet <= vet - 1;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
    num <= vet;
end RTL;
```

Comment: You're seeing vet bits propagate at different times, expand the waveform to show individual num bits. As long as there's setup for the next rising edge of clock there is no hazard (you won't get a wrong value for synchronously assigned vet). [Your process could be simplified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeRVY.jpg). If statement conditions are synthesized to match their successive binary evaluation until one is true (check it out). Binary counters wrap so does the arithmetic. You clipped the library clause off the top of your code. You don't need both numeric_std and std_logic_unsigned.

Comment: thank you very much for the help. The only thing that I didn't get is why you declared the signal as an unsigned, can you please tell me the reason?

Comment: Portability, package numeric_std is from the IEEE while std_logic_unsigned is from Synopsys. You only used the "+" operator from  the latter which depends on Synopsys IEEE std_logic_arith not numeric_std for type, function declarations. The two are incompatible, any homographs in the second listed would not be visible by use clause. std_logic_vector arithmetic performs operand type conversion to unsigned, and result conversion back.  I didn't use IEEE's numeric_std_unsigned  which also provides "+" [std_logic_vector, std_logic_vector **return** std_logic_vector] to avoid requiring -2008.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. now it's clear to me how to use these libraries and how to handle vectors. thanks

Comment: There's probably some routing delay in your final implementation. picosecond glitches should not be an issue, unless you are designing very high speed logic. Did you properly constrain output delays? Constraining is very important in high speed designs.

Comment: No, actually I didn't constraint the output, only the clock. I will do and I'll let you know if the hazards will be deleted